# Plotly Express: how to define default button in an interactive dropdown filter

Tags: plotly, plotly-express

I made a line chart with way too many lines to neatly display, thus, I need to be able to select a grouping variable (`label`) and have it just display the lines in a given category.

For example, I would click `A` in the dropdown and have just the lines corresponding to category `A` show up. In the following, I have provided a working example. The dropdown works perfectly fine for all categories except when I want to go back to default `All`.

Does anybody know how to install a `default` button in the interactive dropdown filter?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

d = {
    'num' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    'label' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
    'color' : ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'blue'],
    'value' : [0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5]
    }

# Build dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Build dropdown Labels
labels = df["label"].unique()
buttonsLabels = [dict(label = "All",
                            method = "restyle",
                            visible=True,
                            args = [
                                {'x' : [df.num]},
                                {'y' : [df.values]},
                                {'color': [df.color]},
                            ]
                            )]

for label in labels:
    buttonsLabels.append(dict(label = label,
                              method = "restyle",
                              visible = True,
                              args = [
                                  {'x' : [df.loc[df['label'] == label, "num"]]},
                                  {'y' : [df.loc[df['label'] == label, "value"]]},
                                  {'color' : [df.loc[df['label'] == label, "color"]]},
                              ]
                              ))

# Display figure
fig = px.line(x = df.num, y = df.value, color=df.color)

fig.update_layout(updatemenus = [
   dict(buttons = buttonsLabels, showactive = True),
   ])

fig.show()
```